# Raphaeljs animate path after interval

Tags: path, jquery-animate, raphael, intervals

I have a path which I want to animate every 5 seconds. I tried the using setInterval in the  following code but it keeps duplicating the canvas. Is there an easier solution?

JS Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/DRQDP/1/)

```
window.onload= function aa () {

    paper = Raphael(0,0,900,900);    

    var p=paper.path("M10,10 h20 v10 h-20z");
    p.animate({path:"M10,10 h300 v10 h-300z"},5000);

    //window.setInterval(aa(), 5000);
}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeating the whole `aa` function that initializes the raphael paper (`paper = Raphael(0,0,900,900);`). That's why your canvas gets duplicated.
Moreover, it would be better to use callbacks (you can see the [the docs](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate) on `animate`) rather than `setInterval` to trigger your animations.
This is how I would code it :

```
function init(){
    var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 900, 900),
        pathsString = ["M10,10 h20 v10 h-20z","M10,10 h300 v10 h-300z"],
        p = paper.path(pathsString[0]),
        animationCounter = 0, 
        animationDuration = 5000,
        animate = function(){
            animationCounter++;
            p.animate({path : pathsString[animationCounter %2]}, animationDuration, animate);
        };

    animate();
};
window.onload = init;​
```

Here's [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DRQDP/3/) of the above code.